# add data dynamically from JSON array to HTML table using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, json

php file:

```
   <?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1");
mysql_select_db("test"); 
$sql=mysql_query("select first,last,email,city from userdata"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output)); 
   mysql_close(); 
?>
```

json output:

```
[{"first":"nag","last":"ch","email":"nag@gmail.com","city":"guntur"},{"first":"hari","last":"ch","email":"hari@gmail.com","city":"guntur"}]
```

html code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).show(function(){
    });

        $("#userdata tbody").html("");
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/reg/userdata.php",function(data){
              $.each(data,function(i,user){
                    var tblRow =
                        "<tr>"
                          +"<td>"+user.first+"</td>"
                          +"<td>"+user.last+"</td>"
                          +"<td>"+user.email+"</td>"
                          +"<td>"+user.city+"</td>"
                        +"</tr>"
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
                });
            }
        );
    </script>
```

i was displayed data from database using php in JSON format..i want to insert this data into table format in html page, i created table in html also..i tried using above script but it didn't fetch any data..plz help me plz..

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that JSON output? I am not sure how you are getting all those results from that select query - I would expect to see a single field for each array entry.

Answer (score 0):

According by your php code, the `data` is an array, and there is no `userdata` property.

```
$.each(data.userdata, function(i,user){
```

should be

```
$.each(data, function(i,user){
```

***[THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mxcWm/3/)***.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is printing the array in an incremented format.

Make the following changes:

```
print(json_encode($row));
```

Next, there is no **userdata** in the output, so just use `data`.

Comment: am not getting output...it shows empty table, will u plz modify the code plz

Comment: @user1310385, I would to be happy to fix the problem. Create your issue in jsfiddle.net and post the link :)

Comment: now i am using localhost..can we create demo even if u are using localhost.

Comment: Just use the js and html portion, the php is not required to show the issue i guess.

Comment: i have sent the link plz check it once

Comment: Hi All,
I really appreciate your help so far. I was trying to follow various tutorials available online and tried the above mentioned procedure. Unfotunately it didnt work out. Now I was debugging the html page using firebug and noticed that there is a reference error on the data (function(data)). Can some one please help me out on understanding how to make this work. Though this might be a minor fix, as I am a new bee to php I could not figure it out. Please try to help me get out of this assignment. Thanks in advance!